# Daedalus only has two translated languages. Can the community add more?

Tags: wallet, daedalus

I want to help translating Daedalus to Brazilian Portuguese. Where can I find instructions on how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

From what I read here at https://github.com/input-output-hk/daedalus/issues/2423 (open on Mar 2, closed on Mar 3), there is indeed only 2 languages, English and Japanese, and yes the community already proposed for more translations, but as of now they will focus on the two actual as adding a new language requires to check carefully “every single line of text”. The verdict is that translations cannot be done by external contributions as it requires “internal people that are always present” for last-minutes changes.

I might propose that you could help translating other projects related to Cardano, for example maybe you could connect with people from specific staking pools!

It is a great initiative. :)